# easy_install not working on OS X

Tags: python-2.7, easy-install

I seem to have screwed up my Python install on my Mac (running OSX 10.10.3), I can run `python` but not `easy_install`. Running `easy_install` just gives me

> sudo: easy_install: command not found

However, `sudo easy_install-3.4 pip` doesn't give me any error but when I then try to use pip using `pip install gevent` I get

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory

If I use `pip3.4 install gevent`I get a long set of errors ending with

> Cleaning up...
>   Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/sb/bk7v6n4x30s6c_w_p3jf7mrh0000gn/T/pip_build_Oskar/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/sb/bk7v6n4x30s6c_w_p3jf7mrh0000gn/T/pip-q7w99lz8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/sb/bk7v6n4x30s6c_w_p3jf7mrh0000gn/T/pip_build_Oskar/gevent
>   Storing debug log for failure in /var/folders/sb/bk7v6n4x30s6c_w_p3jf7mrh0000gn/T/tmpoowjltmj

How can I restore my Python setup?

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently upgraded your OS?  Sometimes the X-Code Command Line Tools need to be re-installed after an OS upgrade.